# Oшибка: Variable required E2036 Delphi XE. Что делать?

Tags: delphi

Присвоение указателю адреса bitmap'a image'a.

```
var b1:^tbitmap;
begin
    b1:=@image1.Picture.Bitmap;   <---------- здесь возникает ошибка
end;
```

Comment: Мобыть @(image1.Picture.Bitmap) ?

*не уверен*

Comment: нет. Variable required E2036 Delphi XE((((((((((((

Comment: Быть может, надо указать, что класс TBitmap принадлежит Graphics::, а не Windows::

Answer (score 0, accepted):

почему вам просто не присвоить знаечение или открыть с помощью 
`b1.Assign(Image1.Picture.Bitmap);`